# WiFi connection doesn't work in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, WiFi connection doesn't work, 
after searching I found that run following commands and then restart the machine solve the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

But this issue happened each time I shutdown the machine. So, it's not reliable to do this each time!!

Update:
Output of grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/* command is:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb
```

Output of rfkill list command is:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: It makes no sense to do it each time. These commands remove a wrong package and installs the correct one. `sudo modprobe b43` will be sufficient. But I think the problem is that `b43` is blacklisted manually. Please post output of `grep b43 /etc/modprobe.d/*` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 The output is: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:# replaced by b43 and ssb.

Comment: Please add the full output TO YOUR QUESTION. Also please add output of `rfkill list` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 updated!

Comment: All looks OK. Does `sudo modprobe b43` fix the problem after a shutdown? Another question. After shutdown does `rfkill list` show the same?

Comment: Just test it, the problem solved! Thank you, and yes rfkill list show the same output

Comment: It is not solved if you have to run it each time.

Comment: I've shutdown again and WiFi  works  directly.

Comment: This means that the problem was that you installed a wrong driver. Don't to it again. It is suggested, but still don't.

Comment: I didn't sure  if I understand your last comment!

Comment: You probably install `bcmwl-kernel-source` using Additional Drivers GUI. That leads to your problem, not a restart. With my commands we didn't do anything persistent.

Comment: So, what is the persistent solution?!

Comment: No need to do anything if it works now. Otherwise add a `blabla.conf` file to `/etc/modprobe.d` containing `modprobe b43`.

Comment: You could try `sudo depmod -a` and see if it works correctly